# any method to export dashboards on pentaho and reused on another pentaho BI server?

Tags: pentaho

I have made some dashboards on pentaho BI server. I want to export them and import on another pentaho BI server. Is there any method to realize this? we have the same datasource.

Comment: which pentaho version are you using ?

Comment: currently I am using version 5.2

Answer (score 0):

In Pentaho 5 version, you can use User Console to Download the Dashboard files. It will get download in zip format. Once it is done, take these codes to the New BI Server, use the user console and UPLOAD it.

For e.g : If you have a project folder named "PROJECT_XYZ" then open the user console, select the project folder >> on the right hand screen you will find "DOWNLOAD" option. Just click on it and the project folder will get downloaded in .zip format. Take this .zip file and UPLOAD it in the new Server using the user console (of the new server).

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**For Exporting:**

import-export.bat --export --url=http://localhost:8080/pentaho --username=admin --password=admin --charset=UTF-8 --path=/public --file-path=E:/pentaho/shaz.zip --overwrite=true --permission=true -retainOwnership=true

**For Importing:**

import-export.bat --import --url=http://localhost:8080/pentaho --username=admin --password=admin --charset=UTF-8 --path=/public --file-path=E:/pentaho/anyfile.zip --overwrite=true --permission=true -retainOwnership=true